# token validation in angular for protecting routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jwt

can anyone let know how can we validate the token stored in local storage for routing protection
I have saw some of tutorials but all of them checking if there is any token is present  in local storage or not like below4

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private routes: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < boolean > | Promise < boolean > | boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.routes.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }

  }
}
```

and we can easily bypass this  method by creating a token with random value

can anyone let me know more efficient way to validate the login token?

token validation in angular authguard

Comment: Validation can only happen on the _server_. Every validation that is performed on the client (for example, in angular) can be cirumvented, as you observed.

Comment: Just to add one addition to HeikoTheißen's reply. It doesn't matter if you set a random value, it matters when you use that random value, you have to send that to your server, and that's where validation happens.

Answer (score -1):

As rightly said by Heiko & Jimmy, its not the secure way to validate token at the client side.

However, assuming that you want to implement it at client side only without any server validation.

To do that in the client side
This is the best article I suggest
https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/best-practices-for-jwt-authentication-in-angular-apps.aspx